# Printing the PID of a program immediately before it runs

Tags: c, child-process

I need to know (for monitoring purposes) the PID of a program immediately before I start it. There could be multiple of the same program launched at the same time, so monitoring `ps` or `top` isn't really an option. It dawned on me as I was exploring various `bash`-related options that I could make use of C's `exec` functions to try and pull this off. With that in mind, I whipped up this little piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char **argv_copy;
    int i;

    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        argv_copy = malloc(argc * sizeof *argv_copy);

        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            argv_copy[i-1] = argv[i];
        }
        argv_copy[argc] = (char *) NULL;

        printf("%lu\n", (long unsigned) getpid());

        execvp(argv[1], argv_copy);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works as expected - it immediately prints out the PID of the process and then loads the *actual* process I want to run. What I'm not convinced of is the security or robustness of this little hack. I don't need it to be 100% bullet-proof security-wise, but if you can drive an SUV through it I'd like to know.

Could I get some advice on these two areas specifically?

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. What this means is that if you wish to share the updated version... you should post it as a self-answer (as a proper review), or as a github link in the question, or perhaps as a new question to be reviewed?

Comment: Hello! Please don't make changes to the original post once it has been reviewed, as that invalidates the current answers. Please see our meta side on [performing iterative reviews](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) for more information!

Comment: @Pimgd and syb0rg: Oops, didn't see that when I read the "how to ask a good question" FAQs. Sorry!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Bug

This line:

> ```
>     argv_copy[argc] = (char *) NULL;
> ```

should be:

```
    argv_copy[argc-1] = NULL;
```

You are removing one argument so you need to terminate the array at the right place.

#### Copy unneeded

Instead of:

> ```
>     execvp(argv[1], argv_copy);
> ```

you could do:

```
    execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
```

and avoid making a copy.

Comment: I completely forgot that C arrays are contiguous in memory... this makes perfect sense. Seems I've been working in Python a little too long haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It fails silently when you pass it gibberish. Not quite a bug, but still not the best.

```
$ ./a.out nemo
8620
$ echo $?
0

$ nemo
bash: nemo: command not found
$ echo $?
127
```

An easy fix would be to print an error message and return 127 after the `execvp`.

Comment: It's also a silent no-op when run without any arguments, when one would expect it to error out with a usage message instead.

Answer (score 7):

Note that you can also do this trivially with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "PID: $$"
exec "$@"
```

That's a lot simpler and less bug-prone than doing it in C.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, sorry.

I might be totally wrong here but [the man page for getpid()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) states that it returns the PID of the calling process.
This would be your application instead of the one you want to execute.

So instead of printing the PID of a program immediately before it runs, you print the PID of a program immediatly before another program runs.

Comment: From what I recall, exec runs the new binary in the process that calls it, it doesn't spawn a new one, which is why you often see a fork/exec pattern.

Comment: On Unix-like systems `execvp()` (and friends) do not start a new process, they _replace_ the current one. `fork()` is the call to start a new process, it copies the calling process. Of course one often calls `fork` and then almost immediately `exec`, but the fact that they are separate allows for some interesting things. Like this one.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it replaces the current process. It all makes sense now. :)

Answer (score 0):

`pid_t` is certainly *some* integer type.

Looking forward, little reason to assume an `unsigned long` is sufficient range to encompass a `pid_t`.

So why be stingy? Use a *very wide* type when trying to print types of unknown width.

```
//printf("%lu\n", (long unsigned) getpid());
printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t) getpid());
// or 
printf("%lld\n", (long long) getpid());
```

If absolutely certain, use the unsigned counter parts.

---

For completeness, code should `free()` memory it allocates.

Comment: If the call succeeds, you don't actually need to `free` this memory, as the `exec` call would wipe out the heap/data section. But I guess if it fails, then you're right!

Comment: @tonysdg Agree with little "need" to call `free()`.  It is just that I look at all _good_ code as re-usable for other tasks - there `free()` may be needed.  Putting your toys away when done playing is good house-keeping and good coding style.

Comment: I think that's my new favorite metaphor for `malloc`/`free`.